# Javascript alert on function inside a php site?

Tags: php

Alright so i'd like to request some help regarding a simple php code.
I disabled right mouse clicking (I know you can call me dumb but I have good reasoning) and I want a pop-up on right mouse click to send a message to the client.

```
  echo '  <script>

var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Astoria") ? 1 : 0;

if(navigator.appName == "Astoria") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);

    echo '  <script>

var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Astoria") ? 1 : 0;

if(navigator.appName == "Astoria") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler(){

return false;

var message="Right-clicking is disabled";

}

function mousehandler(e){

var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;

var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;

if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;

}

document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;

document.onmousedown = mousehandler;

document.onmouseup = mousehandler;

</script>';
```

it's what I have for now, thanks c:

Comment: What's the question? SO is for coding issues, not to rewrite your code(s). Are you having a specific coding issue?

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to add the actual function of the popup in a php script

Comment: I suggest you read about the difference in server and client side programming/scripting. PHP runs on the server and has nothing to do with code that runs on the client (except that PHP can construct this code and return in to the client).

Comment: Where is the popup in this script? The `echo '  <script>` needs `<?php` tags and is invalid as is (I'm not really clear what you are doing there). PHP also is server side so all the processing is done before the page loads or via AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either messed up your quotes and script tags (which you probably have) or you have a Javascript error.

Pop ups in PHP work, small example here:

```
<?php

echo '<script>alert("I am a pop-up!")</script>'

?>
```

(Although I don't think it is good practice because JS is on the front end and php on the back end.